# Update PHP page and insert into db

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I am currently trying to set up a login and register page in PHP and MySQL. I have an external connection.php page that connects to a DB and prints a success image (which is posted at the top of every webpage, so it works). In my current code, I am not getting any output at all from the whats in the PHP tags. Once the register is pressed I don't get any error messages (if I try doing a simple echo statement, nothing gets printed either). The page just reloads and that's that. When I check my DB the data isn't inserted. I figure if I can get some sort of output I can debug the rest myself, but I am not even getting that. I tried adding "global $conn;" to see if the scope is the issue, but that's, not the case.

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";

    if($_POST['register']) {
        #Check to see which button was pressed
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        echo $username . " " . $password;

        #First check to see if username is already selected
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=$username");
$query->execute();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
            echo "Account already exists. Please try again.";
        } else {
            $insert = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)');
            $insert->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
            $insert->execute() or die (mysqli_error());
            echo "Successfuly Registered";
        }
    }



 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>UND Bookstore Login</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
        <meta name="author" content="Sai Peri"></meta>
        <meta name="description" content="CSCI 457 Assignment 1"></meta>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest jQuery libraries -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse text-center">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                                <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Add/Delete/Edit</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                </div> <!-- End col-md-12 -->
            </div>  <!-- End row (nav)-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Login below <small>Or register below</small></h3>
                    </div> <!-- End of page-header -->
                </div> <!-- End col-md-12 -->
            </div> <!-- End row (nav)-->
            <div class="row" id="body">
                <!-- Add text boxes and buttons -->
                <form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login">Login</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="register">Register</button>
                    </div> <!-- End form-group -->
                </form>

            </div> <!-- End of row -->
            <div class="row" id="footer">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <footer>Created 2019 by Sai Peri</footer>
                </div> <!-- End col-md-12 -->
            </div> <!-- End row (nav)-->
        </div> <!-- End container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

SOLVE: The issue was solved using the following statement isset($_POST['register']) or by doing !empty($_POST...) and adding values to the input tags.

Comment: Try putting `var_dump($_POST)` at the top and post what is printed from that when you press the register submit button.

Comment: I get the output "string(0) "" " when I do $_POST['register'] but "array(3) { ["username"]=> string(4) "asdf" ["password"]=> string(4) "asdf" ["register"]=> string(0) "" } " when I do _POST. So the data is getting passed properly...

Comment: What file is the above code in, login.php?

Comment: Why are you expecting something to be in the `register` index? Are you actually pressing the register button?

Comment: Yes, I want to 1. Register the accounts by entering it into the DB and 2. Reload login.php (current page) with a success message or a failed message.

Comment: Yes. I am using _POST['register'] and _POST['login'] as my button names. And a particular action is to be executed depending on what button is pressed.

Comment: Try this: `if(!empty($_POST['register']))` for your if statement. Also, put a value in your button such as `value="register"`. The reason this wasn't working for you is that there was no value passed in your `$_POST['register']` so it is considered to be an empty string, which is a false value.

Comment: you should add that to the other submit as well with value ="login".  you could name both of them buttonPushed and then you just have to check its value

Comment: This seems to work? But the page gets refreshed to a blank one with only the vardump output and what not. I am assuming I have to recopy my html and styling into the php tags? Also my db doesn't get updated and no errors get printed...

Comment: Bind `$username` as you do for the `insert`. Use error reporting. Hash your passwords. Don't mix procedural, `mysqli_error()`, and OO, use OO everywhere.

Comment: @SaiPeri No, don't duplicate your HTML (you'll never want to do that). Look at your conditional logic and think about what you can do to make the HTML conditionally display. If you want to display the error message within the HTML you could define a variable up top and then echo that within your HTML when it is defined: `<?php if(isset($errorMessage)): ?> <div class="error-box"><?=$errorMessage?></div> <?php endif; ?>`